# Firefox addon - Notification bar with timer

Tags: firefox, timer, firefox-addon, notifications

In a Firefox add-on, I would like to set a temporary notification the top notification bar. By temporary, I mean that the notification would disappear after a couple seconds. Is this something possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications don't have an automatic timeout, but you can set your own timeout and call `removeNotification` to remove it.

```
var box = bar.appendNotification(label, value, image, priority, buttons);
setTimeout(function() { bar.removeNotification(box); }, delay);
```

Comment: Cool, now to figure out a way to toast a message in a restartless (aka Jetpack aka SDK) add-on...